# Origin of amp-iframe must not be equal to container if allow-same-origin is set

Tags: iframe, amp-html

I'm getting this error:

```
Origin of <amp-iframe> must not be equal to container
<amp-iframe sandbox=​"allow-scripts allow-same-origin" layout=​"nodisplay" frameborder=​"0" src=​"https:​/​/​localhost:​3000/​team-tracker-frame.html?team=reading" class=​"i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-error i-amphtml-layout">​…​</amp-iframe>​ 
if allow-same-origin is set. 
See https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-iframe-origin-policy.md for details.
```

My amp iframe looks like this (this is a pug template):

```
<amp-iframe 
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" 
  layout="nodisplay" frameborder="0" 
  src="https://localhost:3000/team-tracker-frame.html?team=reading">
</amp-iframe>
```

My understanding and intuition tells me that by supplying `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` should allow this frame to be loaded successfully.

Followed by another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null` thrown by amp-iframe.js

Can anyone shed some light on this. Surely "ALLOW-same-origin" means I should be able to have an iframe on the same host, i.e. localhost:3000

I've also noticed that using amp-web-push allows you to set an iframe (helper-iframe-url="https://localhost:3000/amp-web-push-helper-frame.html") which amp happily will load on the same origin with the same sandbox settings.

Answer (score 2):

As amp suggests 'One can easily circumvent AMP's not-same-origin-enforcement through redirects, since only the initial URL is tested'.

To get a redirect i am using url generated from tinyURL site. I created a tinyURL of my url and placed in src or amp-iframe and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that iframes on the same origin can access the parent document if `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` are combined.

> Setting both the allow-scripts and allow-same-origin keywords together
>   when the embedded page has the same origin as the page containing the
>   iframe allows the embedded page to simply remove the sandbox attribute
>   and then reload itself, effectively breaking out of the sandbox
>   altogether.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

AMP Pages, however, must be built in a way so that they can be served from a different origin (e.g. cdn.ampproject.org). If `amp-iframe` would allow setting `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` for same origin iframes, behaviour could break if an AMP document is served from a different origin. To avoid this, iframes need to be served from a different (sub) domain when using `allow-same-origin`.